# Sequential case autoincrementing its variable

Tags: bash, case

This potentially is a stupid question or an impossible request. Anyway, I'm writing a little script to launch a program chosen from a list of installed software. Basically, my script presents me a numbered list, in which the programs are listed alphabetically, and I input the number corresponding to the program I want to launch. The variable in which my choice is stored is sent to a `case`, which launches the corresponding software, having its location stored in each case's command list.

```
i=1
echo -e "Which program to launch?\n"$((i++))". Program 1\n"$((i++))". Program 2\n"
read choice
case $choice in
        1)  path to program 1
        2)  path to program 2
esac
```

As you see, in the `echo` I've used a variable which gets incremented every time a new program is listed. This, to avoid having to manually write static numbers I have to personally shift every time a new program is installed and has to be inserted in the list between two existing programs. All I need to do is copy the universal `$((i++))` index and the list adjusts itself.

The problem is I don't know how to implement this in the `case` cycle. Supposing I install a Program 3 which has to be alphabetically put between the two existing ones, the `echo` gets modified this way

```
echo -e "Which program to launch?\n"$((i++))". Program 1\n"$((i++))". Program 3\n"$((i++))". Program 2\n"
```

But in the `case`, I manually have to change the `2)` before the second program into a `3)`.

```
case $choice in
        1)  path to program 1
        2)  path to program 3
        3)  path to program 2
esac
```

This may not be a problem in his example, but it is now that I have dozens of programs, and I have to change the 5 into a 6, the 6 into a 7 and so on until more than 20.

How can I automatize the `case` numbering, so that the cycle understands on its own that has to execute the n-th case if the variable value is n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash already has `select` which does what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
select choice in ls date 'ls /' ; do
    $choice
    break
done
```

If you want to present something different to what you run, you can use an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A choices=(
    [show files]=ls
    [show date]=date
    [list root dir]='ls /'
)
select choice in "${!choices[@]}" exit ; do
    [[ $choice == exit ]] && break
    ${choices[$choice]}
done
```

`exit` is handled outsice of the associative array as we want to keep it last, but associative arrays are unordered.

Comment: This way, can I give completely separate and different commands for each choice, or do I have to rely on the variable `$choice` itself to make my different command?

Comment: One comment on the update: don't try to store anything more complicated than a single command *name* in the associative array. Anything more complicated should be wrapped in a function whose name can be stored in the array.